# Is there a sensible way to use effect size in logistic regression for a priori power analysis of linear regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, linear, statistical-power

A previous study had participants make a dichotomous decision, and it was analyzed with logistic regression.

A follow-up study is measuring the same construct, but having participants make a continuous decision (i.e., Likert scale from 1-7).

I've had success using the simr package in R to simulate data and figure out the power with N participants if I were to run another study using logistic regression.

However, is there a sensible way to use the effect size from the study using logistic regression, to determine power and sample size for the study with a continuous DV, analyzed with linear regression?

In case it's relevant, all of these studies are analyzed with mixed effects models, including random subject intercepts, and analyzed at the trial level.